# How do I pull a specific record from an SQL database I've set up using C, and then store part of that record in a variable?

Tags: c, database, string, sqlite, interface

So, there are plenty of questions about SQLite in here and plenty of questions about C, but I've found comparatively few about doing C-SQLite interface operations.

I'm in the process of teaching myself about C-SQL interfacing. I work for a small company writing software that interfaces with SQL databases, and most of it is written in C.

As a project, I'm writing some code that uses SQLite3 to create a small local database containing a table of a few hundred names, each of which has an integer ID.

Currently, I'm attempting to write a function that, when called, randomly selects one of the names in the database and returns a string representation of that name to whatever code called my function.

For example, if my database table was something like:

```
ID  |  Name
____________
1    Adam
2    Beth
3    Sarah
4    David
5    Ethan
```

..I'd want my getName() function to pick a random number from 1-5, get the associated name from the table, and then stick that name (and nothing else) into a char* variable that I could then return from the function.

I've been going off of [this example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_c_cpp.htm) on how to set up and access/populate a simple local database, but it's a little light on details beyond setup and printing the entire database (as opposed to a single record) to the terminal.

Here's the code I have so far in the random-name-fetching method. You can assume the code to initialize the database and populate it is working as intended:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <time.h>

char* getName()
{
   //Function variables
   char* str;
   time_t t;

   //SQL operation variables
   sqlite3 *db;
   char *zErrMsg = 0;
   int rc;
   int dbSize;
   char sql[50];

   //Init. randomizer
   srand((unsigned) time(&t));

   //SQL COMMAND 1
   snprintf(sql, sizeof(sql), "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE;");

   //SQL COMMAND 2
   snprintf(sql, sizeof(sql), "SELECT NAME FROM TABLE WHERE ID = %d;", (rand() % dbSize));

   return str;
}
```

What I need to do is to store the results of passing the sql string that I build at SQL COMMAND 1 to SQLite's sqlite3_exec function. This will, hopefully, be an integer, or a string that I can convert to an integer. I'll use this integer to make sure the random number generated by rand() actually corresponds to one of the IDs that's on the table.

After that, I want to store the results of passing the sql string that I build at SQL COMMAND 2 to the exec function in a string variable, and return that variable from the function.

You can assume I've set the database up successfully and have a working callback function. All I really want to do is the random name selection I've described.

If anyone knows how to do *this specifically*, I'd really appreciate the expertise.

Comment: You aren't using *any* of the SQLite API's to interface with the database. See the QuickStart in the [docs](https://sqlite.org/quickstart.html)

Comment: "You can assume the code to initialize the database and populate it is working as intended." I was using the APIs in the rest of my code, and it was working correctly. Not reading + linking me to the literal first page of the documentation = not very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Executing a statement from SQLite in C is pretty easy. You make a string of an SQL query and pass it to the SQLite_exec function after you open the database. Plenty of examples of this in the tutorial I linked above.

That tutorial doesn't show you how to get the data you want and store it in a variable, though. Here's how you ACTUALLY do that, pulled from [this excellent tutorial](https://zetcode.com/db/sqlitec/) on SQL in C.

Here's an example of simply pulling a table-size-count from a previously created database with a table in it. Look at either tutorial on how to do that if you don't know; this example assumes it already exists.

```
    char *errMsg = 0;
    int rc;
    int step;
    sqlite3_stmt *res;
    char *sql;
    int dbSize;
    sqlite3* db;

    //Open database
    rc = sqlite3_open("test.db", &db);
    
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) 
    {    
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        sqlite3_close(db);
        
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    //Make SQL statement
    sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE;";
    
    //Compile the statement   
    rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &res, 0);
    
    if (rc == SQLITE_OK) 
    {
       //Do Nothing
    } 
    else 
    { 
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to execute statement: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    }
    
    //Run the statement
    sqlite3_step(res);
    
    //GET THE DATA HERE
    printf("Count is: %s\n", sqlite3_column_text(res, 0));

    sqlite3_close(db);
```

The sqlite3_column_text() method actually retrieves data from the query, and the int you pass to it is the index of the data you want. If I had three more results in the row from the DB query, I'd just call it with indices 1, 2 and 3 to get the others. I'm passing it to a print method, but you can just as easily stick the result into a char* variable and call it a day.